# MYSQL query group by and cumulative sum for financial orderbook

Tags: mysql, sum, orderbook

Hello i have the following dataset

```
id price amount
1    10    1
2    20    2
3    20    1.5
4    21    1
5    21    2
```

```
SELECT amount, price, (@CumulativeSum := @CumulativeSum + amount) AS CumSum 
FROM orderbook
```

And it is working fine. I would like to populate my python dictionary using also a "GROUP BY price" clause but this is affecting my final result. The final data should show the SUM of the amounts grouped by price.

I tried the following queries

```
SELECT amount, price, (@CumulativeSum := @CumulativeSum + amount) AS CumSum 
FROM orderbook  
GROUP BY price

SELECT SUM(amount), price, (@CumulativeSum := @CumulativeSum + amount) AS CumSum 
FROM orderbook  
GROUP BY price

SELECT amount, price, (@CumulativeSum := @CumulativeSum + SUM(amount)) AS CumSum 
FROM orderbook
```

But the cumulative sum or the grouped sums are always wrong.

The final result should be a simple order book for a financial market.

The desired output is

```
price amount CumSum
10    1     1
20    3.5   4.5
21    3     7.5
```

Thanks for the hints

Comment: HINT: [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: HINT: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry: Thanks 

Comment: *I would like to populate my python dictionary using also a "GROUP BY price" clause* o_O Show desired output.

Comment: i edited my question with the desired output of my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use mysql 5.7 (since this version is using by me). you want to sum cummulative from the result of amount on each price, so you should use `SUBQUERY` in order to aggregation

Try this:

```
    set @CumulativeSum := 0;
    SELECT price, summ,
   (@CumulativeSum:= @CumulativeSum + summ) as cumsum 
      FROM (SELECT SUM(amount) as Summ
             FROM (SELECT * FROM orderbook) a
             GROUP BY price
             ORDER BY price) b
```

result

```
+-------+------+--------+
| price | summ | cumsum |
+-------+------+--------+
|    10 | 1.00 | 1.00   |
|    20 | 3.50 | 4.50   |
|    21 | 3.00 | 7.50   |
+-------+------+--------+
```

this is the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4f607e38a23f069829dfaa177a8bc3d3